# React.NET, Webpack - 'ReactDOM' is undefined (client side)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, webpack

Following the tutorial [here](http://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html), I have managed to get webpack doing my bundling for me, and it is working for pre-rendering on the server side, e.g.:

```
@Html.React("Components.myComponent",
             New With {
                 .initialData = Nothing
             })

@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

This is correctly displaying my component in the browser, but as soon as the client takes over I get the error `'ReactDOM' is undefined`

I have installed the `react-dom` using `npm install react-dom --save-dev`
I have tried to `require` the ReactDOM, first in the .jsx file containing my component, then in the client.js file that webpack is building from:

```
//myComponent.jsx
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

or

```
//client.js
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Components = require('expose?Components!./src');
```

But I am still getting the same error.

If I add the `react` and `react-dom` scripts directly above my webpack compiled client javascript, then the problem goes away:

```
//index.html
<script src="https://www.facebook.com/react-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.facebook.com//react-dom-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/webpack/build/client.bundle.js"></script>
```

So how can I get webpack to properly include these scripts in the client bundle?

**EDIT**

I did have the following `externals` in my `webpack.config.js`, but removing them doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
externals: {
    // Use external version of React (from CDN for client-side, or
    // bundled with ReactJS.NET for server-side)
    react: 'React'
}
```

I guess, externals are there so you *can* use CDN based scripts, so maybe I am overthinking this one and should just leave the CDN based react scripts in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should expose `react-dom` globally in your `client.js`, so it will be available in browser in `ReactDOM` variable to render client-side:

```
require("expose?ReactDOM!react-dom");
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! i had worked around it but that makes lots of sense now, thanks :)

Comment: Isn't that essentially what line `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` is supposed to do?

Comment: `@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` does not expose `react-dom` on client side, it is server side method to render script like `<script>ReactDOM.render(...)</script>` (according to documentation from https://reactjs.net/features/server-side-rendering.html)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks for confirming